# No internet when charging in Ubuntu 20.04 - Dual booted Windows 11 no issues

Tags: networking, internet, power-management, dns, battery

Whenever I plug in my charger, I lose internet connection. I do not lose wifi connection, the wifi signal stays strong. I just can't get any data or very little data through it when my charger is plugged in.

I have a dual-booted Windows11 and Ubuntu20.04 system on an Asus Zenbook. There are no issues with the Windows side so it can't be a hardware issue right?

I have tons of other devices on this internet connection that never have any issues, so I don't think it's a router/modem/ISP problem either (Xfinity with modem/router combo).

I can plug in an ethernet cable and have no issues at all, charging or not.

When I unplug my charger, sometimes I have to restart network manager to get the connection going again (`sudo service network-manager restart`). Other times I can just unplug it and get data immediately.

With my charger unplugged I can ping google.com just fine:

```
➜  ~ ping google.com
PING google.com(ord30s31-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ord37s51-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=12.1 ms
64 bytes from ord37s51-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=14.9 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.058/13.490/14.922/1.432 ms
```

When I plug the charger back in and try to `ping google.com` it just hangs or sometimes some packets will come through but very slowly. Eventually I start to see `ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available` or sometimes `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

When I try to ping my Xfinity's DNS while unplugged everything looks fine.

When I try to ping the DNS while charging:

```
➜  ~ ping 75.75.75.75
PING 75.75.75.75 (75.75.75.75) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 75.75.75.75: icmp_seq=7 ttl=57 time=162 ms
64 bytes from 75.75.75.75: icmp_seq=8 ttl=57 time=15.9 ms
64 bytes from 75.75.75.75: icmp_seq=9 ttl=57 time=14.4 ms
^C
--- 75.75.75.75 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 3 received, 66.6667% packet loss, time 8133ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.417/63.960/161.550/69.009 ms
```

Here is my iwconfig:

```
➜  ~ iwconfig wlo1
wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"VirusDownloader"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: E4:BF:FA:8A:94:54   
          Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:3  Invalid misc:186   Missed beacon:0
```

Here is my /etc/resolv.conf

```
➜  ~ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search hsd1.il.comcast.net
nameserver 75.75.75.75
nameserver 75.75.76.76
nameserver 2001:558:feed::1
# NOTE: the libc resolver may not support more than 3 nameservers.
# The nameservers listed below may not be recognized.
nameserver 2001:558:feed::2
```

I have tried turning off power management mode of the wlo1 connection and it does nothing.

```
➜  ~ sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
...
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
...
➜  ~ sudo service network-manager restart
```

I have tried manually changing my DNS in `/etc/resolv.conf' and it did not help.

I have tried every combination of IPv4, IPv6, DHCP, Automatic DHCP, manually setting DNS, and all other settings of the wifi connection in the Ubunutu settings app and nothing helped.

I have quickboot and safeboot both turned off in UEFI settings.

**Here's where it gets really weird:** When I connect to my phone's hotspot, there are no connection issues, charging or not. Also, I have previously had different internet with this same machine and never had any issues. It's like its the combination of my router/modem and my power being plugged in?

Any help would be much appreciated. I am totally stumped on this one.

**Edit:** I have tried suggestion by @Terrance, splitting the 2.4 and 5Ghz channels on my router and it didn't help.

**Edit:** I am also noticing some strange behavior occasionally when I plug the charging cord in, it makes a noise but the battery icon never changes to the charging icon. This happens randomly and not all the time. Doesn't seem to have any effect on the internet connection.

Comment: You do have a very strange and unique issue here.  I am just going to throw this out there, but I have seen where having the 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz channels on routers named the same causing confusion in devices.  Not every device necessarily gets confused, but it can happen.  My friend would constantly get slow internet speeds with his Xfinity until he separated his channels with separate names.  I am thinking that is why it works with your phone's hotspot because it is only 1 channel and not 2 combined.

Comment: I second @Terrance 's explanation. The only thing I can think of is that somehow charging is interfering with either the 2.4Ghz or the 5Ghz channel (whichever Ubuntu uses by default) and your phone only has the other one available. Windows may by default be using the same band that your phone provides, or it switches when necessary, so it never encounters the interference. Try separating the two on your router (give different SSIDs) and see if one of the two works while charging.

Comment: Thank you @Terrance and Esther for the input but unfortunalely, I have already tried this.. Forgot to mention it in the original post. Just tried it again for good measure and still nothing. Will edit OP.

Comment: Maybe some energy saving software like TLP is installed and is doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6 your response was actually what got me thinking and looking in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I think I got this sorted.. I noticed in my syslog that the network adapter kept restarting when the machine was plugged into power. Still not sure why. This is the log that tipped me off, I saw it every minute or so:

```
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.066815] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Queue 10 is active on fifo 1 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [201, 101] HW [201, 101] FH TRB=0x0c010a0d8
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.066991] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067168] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067174] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067182] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 46.4d093a30.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067188] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067195] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x008026F4 | trm_hw_status0
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067201] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067206] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00488876 | branchlink2
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067211] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00478E36 | interruptlink1
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067215] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00478E36 | interruptlink2
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067220] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B57A | data1
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067225] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | data2
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067229] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF0000008 | data3
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067234] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1940AD53 | beacon time
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067239] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x03547477 | tsf low
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067243] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067248] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067253] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x009D6C95 | time gp2
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067257] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067262] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | uCode version major
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067266] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4D093A30 | uCode version minor
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067271] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000312 | hw version
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067275] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C89008 | board version
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067280] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0AC9001C | hcmd
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067284] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80022002 | isr0
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067289] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067293] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08001802 | isr2
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067297] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0041F4CC | isr3
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067302] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067306] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0063019C | last cmd Id
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067310] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001B57A | wait_event
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067315] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067319] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00002020 | l2p_duration
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067324] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067328] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | l2p_addr_match
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067333] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000D | lmpm_pmg_sel
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067337] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01102344 | timestamp
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067341] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000C8BC | flow_handler
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067389] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067393] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 7
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067398] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067404] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067408] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0088BBE | umac branchlink2
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067413] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084458 | umac interruptlink1
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067417] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084458 | umac interruptlink2
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067422] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000000 | umac data1
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0084458 | umac data2
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067431] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067435] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | umac major
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067439] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4D093A30 | umac minor
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067444] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x009D6C83 | frame pointer
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067448] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC088627C | stack pointer
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067452] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0063019C | last host cmd
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067457] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067486] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067490] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM error/state
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067518] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM data1
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067534] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067544] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x729BBA5F | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067555] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067566] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB89CECBB | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067577] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067588] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE98F54AB | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067599] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x31EF7C0F | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067610] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004C48BB | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067621] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE5151FF2 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067631] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067644] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067657] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067701] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067716] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
Jul 12 12:07:14 Boris-IV kernel: [ 1173.067730] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
```

I saw my machine is using the iwlwifi driver from lshw (last line):

```
sudo lshw -C  network   
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 30
       serial: d0:c6:37:4d:66:f6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-52-generic firmware=46.4d093a30.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- ip=10.0.0.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

The settings for iwlwifi are in /etc/modprobe.d. So I created a new file:

```
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/iwl-custom.conf
```

and added some options I found in [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=254766):

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=0 bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0
options iwlmvm power_scheme=1 
options iwlwifi d0i3_disable=1 
options iwlwifi uapsd_disable=1 
options iwlwifi lar_disable=1
```

Saved it, restarted my machine, and boom, power is connected and I have internet.

Comment: Don't forget that you can accept your own answer.  You won't get any points for accepting your own, but it does help others see that your issue was solve.  =)